# Toggle between two commands with one key at a time

Tags: python, maya, hotkeys, mel

I'd like to make maya switch between top and bottom orthographic views with  one hotkey, front and back with another hotkey, and left and right with a third, like in MODO. That is two commands with one key at a time.
I would like to know how to do that, in Python or Mel in the runtime command editor, and preferably with any other commands that I choose in the future.
Thanks.

Comment: This one's a bit harder than you might think, because you can get the _name_ of a maya camera pretty easily but the only way to be sure it's actually in it's default orientation is to check the actual orientation of the camera:  you can have a camera that started life as a `front` cam but the user has flipped it around so it's facing left -- but as a far as maya knows it's still a front camera.

Do you care about having more cameras than the default front/side/top/persp?

Comment: @theodox is right mayas cameras dont work like people expect. Its also best not to try to force maya to be something else but leverage on what maya is good at eg in maya you do this with tapping space and tapping space. This can however be done but i do not recommend it to be done as it has several serious caveats because maya does not work like max or modo in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually quite simple, I don't really like to play with the default Maya cameras, but I don't think that is a problem here.
All you have to do is multiply by -1 the translate coordinates. and add 180 degrees to the corresponding axis for each camera you want.

```
 def getActiveViewport():
    """Return the active 3D viewport if any"""
    panel = cmds.getPanel(withFocus=True)
    if cmds.getPanel(typeOf=panel) == 'modelPanel':
        return panel
    return ''


def switchcamera(cam):
    viewport = getActiveViewport()
    if viewport:
        orient = {'top': 'X', 'front': 'Y', 'side': 'Y'}
        translate = cmds.getAttr(cam + '.translate')[0]
        translate = [i*-1 for i in translate]
        rotate = cmds.getAttr(cam + '.rotate' + orient[cam])
        rotate = (rotate + 180) % 360
        if rotate < 0:
            rotate = rotate + 360        

        cmds.setAttr(cam + '.translate', *translate, type='double3')
        cmds.setAttr(cam + '.rotate' + orient[cam], rotate)
        cmds.modelPanel(viewport, edit=True, camera=cam)  # Set the camera to the active viewport
```

You can then call those commands with a viewport in focus, and it will automatically switch to the specified camera.

```
switchcamera('top')
switchcamera('front')
switchcamera('side')
```

You could also create new cameras for each orientation -if they don't exists already- and switch back and forth between the default and non-default ones. Without forgetting to copy their translate/rotate attribute, that's the tricky and less elegant part of that solution.

Comment: What do you mean by that? 
You can copy it to your console and execute it to check if it works.
If you mean by that "How do I assign that function to some hotkey/shelf?" that's a totally different question.

You can either copy all the script + the call with the camera you want for each cameras and then duplicate the code. Or put the code in a switchcamera.py file (or whatever you want to call it) in your Maya "scripts" folder and put that in the shortcut you want :
`import switchcameras;switchcameras.switchcamera('top')`